# How can I make get hippie completion with Vim emulation in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm typing an identifier that is long and present somewhere else in the same file, I want to complete it with a keyboard combo in VS Code Vim emulation the same way as I can in Vim (Ctrl-N or Ctrl-P). How can I do that?